# Why I see fielddata when doc_value is enabled in Aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch

Based on [Elastic Documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html), every type except text(an analyzed string) supports `doc_values` which I suppose when available, should completely omit `fielddata` in Aggregation.

However this not the case for me, whenever I do term aggregation based on a `keyword` or `ip` type I see they are loaded as `fieldata`, although this is not happening for other types (e.g **session_id** as `long` type in this case)

Is this the correct behavior? if true, how can I prevent `fielddata` creation?

I'm using elasticsearch 6.5 and This is my mapping

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 2,
      "number_of_replicas": 0,
      "codec": "best_compression"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "time": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "epoch_millis"
        },
        "session_token": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "session_ref": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "session_id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "src": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "version": {
          "type": "byte"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this is a sample aggregation which causes  `fielddata` to get loaded

```
GET test_ind/_search?size=0
  {
  "aggs" : {
    "by_token":{
      "terms":{ 
        "field": "token",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
  }
```

and here is fielddata status after aggregation

```
"test_ind" : {
  "uuid" : "DiB6d7EgSXm7jeiSgoo-mQ",
  "primaries" : {
    "fielddata" : {
      "memory_size_in_bytes" : 1564696,
      "evictions" : 0,
      "fields" : {
        "session_ref" : {
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0
        },
        "session_token" : {
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 1564696
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "total" : {
    "fielddata" : {
      "memory_size_in_bytes" : 1564696,
      "evictions" : 0,
      "fields" : {
        "session_ref" : {
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0
        },
        "session_token" : {
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 1564696
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is segments stat

```
"test_ind" : {
  "uuid" : "DiB6d7EgSXm7jeiSgoo-mQ",
  "primaries" : {
    "segments" : {
      "count" : 8,
      "memory_in_bytes" : 472939,
      "terms_memory_in_bytes" : 423365,
      "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes" : 3504,
      "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
      "norms_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
      "points_memory_in_bytes" : 41598,
      "doc_values_memory_in_bytes" : 4472,
      "index_writer_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
      "version_map_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
      "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
      "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp" : -1,
      "file_sizes" : { }
    }
  },
  "total" : {
    "segments" : {
      "count" : 8,
      "memory_in_bytes" : 472939,
      "terms_memory_in_bytes" : 423365,
      "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes" : 3504,
      "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
      "norms_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
      "points_memory_in_bytes" : 41598,
      "doc_values_memory_in_bytes" : 4472,
      "index_writer_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
      "version_map_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
      "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
      "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp" : -1,
      "file_sizes" : { }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What value do you have in the `...segments.doc_values_memory_in_bytes` of your index stats response?

Comment: @Val the value is "doc_values_memory_in_bytes" : 4472

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently **Global Ordinals** memory usage are shown in `fielddata`](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/why-i-see-fielddata-when-doc-value-is-enabled-in-aggregations/158559).

Global Ordinals can be set to either eager or lazy in mapping, the former would force loading them during refresh time and the latter during query time (default)

to prevent using Global Ordinals in term aggregations we can use `"execution_hint": "map"` which in my case would be:

```
GET test_ind/_search?size=0
  {
  "aggs" : {
    "by_token":{
      "terms":{ 
        "field": "token",
        "execution_hint": "map"
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
  }
```

although it comes with its own caveats, uses more memory for query execution and runs slower.